# Vertical line appearing when manually adjust x-axis range using plotly

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am creating a chart using plotly and would like to extend the x-axis to 0. However, for some reason, when I do this, plotly renders a vertical reference line at 0, as shown below. Is there a way to omit this line and have the vertical line at 0 simply appear gray line the other grid lines?

[image]

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>% 
  plot_ly(
    x = ~mpg, 
    y = ~cyl,
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "markers"
  ) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(
    range = c(0, 35)
  ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `plotly` will automatically draw a `zeroline`. That could be toggled on and off via `layout` argument `zeroline`. If you want a zeroline you could set the color to be equal to the color of the gridlines via `zerolinecolor="#eee"`, where `#eee` is the default grid line color. See [the docs](https://plotly.com/r/reference/layout/xaxis/).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl)) %>% 
  plot_ly(
    x = ~mpg, 
    y = ~cyl,
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "markers"
  ) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(
    range = c(0, 35), 
    zeroline = FALSE
    #zerolinecolor = "#eee"
  ))
```

[image]